# Advanced image layout

Tags: graphics, context

I'm trying to display a set of images this way :

```
————————————————————
|  img1   |        |
|—————————|  img4  |
|img2|img3|        |
————————————————————
```

However I only get

```
———————————
|  img1   |
|—————————|
|img2|img3|
|—————————|
|  img4   |
———————————
```

Here is my code :

```
\placefigure[none]{}
\startcombination[2*1]
{
  \startcombination[1*2]
  {\externalfigure[img1]}{}
  {
    \startcombination[2*1]
    {\externalfigure[img2]}{}
    {\externalfigure[img3]}{}
    \stopcombination
  }{}
  \stopcombination
}{}
{\externalfigure[img4]}{}
\stopcombination
```

Did I miss anything ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is okay to use tables for such alignments. But, you should also get the right output with combinations. What version of context are you using. With `2015.09.13 MkIV`, I get the following output:

[image]

One gets the impression that the layout is messed up, but that is not the case. If you add

```
\showboxes
```

the output is

[image]

which shows that the layout is correct, just that the the images are bottom aligned (the default option) rather than middle aligned). You can change that using the `location=middle` key, or use images of the right dimension.

Here is an example:

```
\useMPlibrary[dum]

\definecombination[grid][inbetween=,distance=0pt,before=,after=]

\starttext
\placefigure[none]{}
\startcombination[grid][2*1]
{
  \startcombination[grid][1*2]
  {\externalfigure[img1][width=8cm,height=3cm]}{}
  {\startcombination[grid][2*1]
    {\externalfigure[img2][width=4cm,height=3cm]}{}
    {\externalfigure[img3][width=4cm,height=3cm]}{}
    \stopcombination}{}
  \stopcombination}{}
{\externalfigure[img4][width=3cm,height=6cm]}{}
\stopcombination
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

And, of course, this is the perfect example to showcase the [`\placekitten`](https://randomdeterminism.wordpress.com/2011/05/07/images-for-documentation-examples/#more-731) macro:

```
\def\externalkitten[#1]%
  {\getparameters[kitten][width=10pt, height=10pt, #1]%
   \externalfigure
      [\ctxlua{context("http://placekitten.com/\letterpercent0.0f/\letterpercent0.0f",
                \withoutpt{\the\dimexpr\kittenwidth},
                \withoutpt{\the\dimexpr\kittenheight})}]
      [#1, method=jpg]}

\definecombination[grid][inbetween=,distance=0pt,before=,after=]

\starttext
\placefigure[none]{}
\startcombination[grid][2*1]
{
  \startcombination[grid][1*2]
  {\externalkitten[width=240pt,height=90pt]}{}
  {\startcombination[grid][2*1]
    {\externalkitten[width=110pt,height=90pt]}{}
    {\externalkitten[width=130pt,height=90pt]}{}
    \stopcombination}{}
  \stopcombination}{}
{\externalkitten[width=90pt,height=180pt]}{}
\stopcombination
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: Indeed my version seems quite old (`context --version` gives ConTeXt Process Management 0.60, current version: 2013.05.28 00:36) and the output is messed up with your example as well.

Comment: It is usually a good idea to use an recent (2-3 month old) ConTeXt. Look at [ConTeXt standalone](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/ConTeXt_Standalone) on the wiki. It can be installed in parallel with Texlive and is easy to update.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure it is the proper way to do that, but I achieved my goal using the following :

```
\startTABLE[frame=off]
  \NC[nx=2] \externalfigure[img1]
  \NC[ny=2] \externalfigure[img4]
  \NC\NR
  \NC \externalfigure[img2][width=2cm]
  \NC \externalfigure[img3][width=2cm]
  \NC\NR
\stopTABLE
```

`[nx=2]` and `[ny=2]` allow to merge cells (colspan and rowspan, respectively).

For the records, previous version, using the "old table syntax" :

```
\bTABLE[frame=off]
  \bTR
      \bTD[nx=2] \externalfigure[img1] \eTD
      \bTD[ny=2] \externalfigure[img4] \eTD
  \eTR
  \bTR
      \bTD \externalfigure[img2][width=2cm] \eTD
      \bTD \externalfigure[img3][width=2cm] \eTD
  \eTR
\eTABLE
```